# Wildcard (*) in the path don't work while copying from cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, path

There is a file (abc.txt) in a folder-
`C:\vackwrk\24may\abc.txt`

and i want to copy that file to another folder using cmd-
`G:\work\`

I use  `copy C:\vackwrk\24may\abc.txt G:\work\`
 this work , but when i am using wildcard it don't work `copy C:\vackwrk\*\abc.txt G:\work\` this time output is - `The filename , directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect`.

Why ? Is there any alternate way to copy using wildcard ?

Comment: Yeah, the windows command line can't do that. And even if it was smarter in general, it still shouldn't: Think what would happen if you had two directories ``C:\vackwrk\foo\`` and ``C:\vackwrk\bar\``, both with a file ``abc.txt``. What would your command do then? Which text file ends up in ``G:\work``?

Comment: Okay thnx , now i am using powershell for copying and wildcard worked this time !

Comment: Please make your solution public ([answer] your own question). In general, I agree with @Antares42 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to use wildcard while copying from cmd because there will be ambiguity to system if there is any other directory `C:\vackwrk\foo\` and `C:\vackwrk\bar\`,both with a file `abc.txt`.

But Windows PowerShell lets you to do copy using wildcard very easily , just need to open cmd and enter `start powershell.exe copy C:\vackwrk\*\abc.txt G:\work\` or simply open Windows PowerShell and enter `PS C:\Windows\system32> copy C:\vackwrk\*\abc.txt G:\work\` .

It works fine , so i think Windows PowerShell is more powerful than cmd.

Comment: What you *can* do on the traditional command line is to put in the wildcard and then press TAB.  If there are multiple matches, pressing TAB again will cycle through them.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, PowerShell calls `CopyFileExW` for every matching file, overwriting the single destination file each time. It doesn't even ask or inform the user! That's reckless. It also expands wildcard tab completion. In PowerShell, pressing `<TAB>` for the input path `C:\*\*\abc.txt` will cycle through matches for every wildcard in the path string. That's nuts. I can only get cmd to complete a wildcard in the final path element such as `C:\vackwrk\foo\ab?.txt`.

Comment: @eryksun: the fact that cmd only tab-completes the most recent element isn't a problem in practice.  It just means you have to press TAB immediately after putting in the wildcard.  Once you've got the directory name you want you can enter the rest of the path.  (Although PowerShell's tab-completion behaviour isn't really a problem either, provided you keep an eye on what it has expanded the path to.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I wasn't saying cmd's behavior is a problem. I prefer only completing wildcards at the leaf node while typing a path. I think PowerShell's behavior is over the top. It can potentially search through thousands of files from the root of the drive. I wouldn't ever use that, except on accident.