# PowerShell allow to use wildcard while copying file but cmd don't allow , why?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Previously i was using cmd to copy file (abc.txt) from `C:\vackwrk\24may\abc.txt` to `G:\work\` and command i used in cmd was `copy C:\vackwrk\*\abc.txt G:\work\` it didn't work but when i use PowerShell it works (file copied to another folder) `PS C:\Windows\system32> copy C:\vackwrk\*\abc.txt G:\work\` ([Wildcard (*) in the path don't work while copying from cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423852/wildcard-in-the-path-dont-work-while-copying-from-cmd))

So, question is - Why cmd don't allow to use wildcard but PowerShell allow ? Is PowerShell better than cmd ?

Comment: Because that wasn't implemented.  Also, this is completely off topic.  Please review the [help] to learn what is and is not on topic.  Protip: if your question doesn't include code, you are probably off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy at the command prompt and copy in PowerShell are completely different.

copy is an [internal command](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html) implemented by cmd.exe itself. It isn't an executable that you can run separately. You can see the help if you run `copy /?`.

copy in PowerShell in an alias to the [`Copy-Item` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849793.aspx). You can see the help by using `help copy`.

The two are superficially similar but actually have some different features. As you've seen, PowerShell will expand any wildcards in the path, not just wildcards in file names. Another difference is that copy in cmd allows you to concatenate files with +, so `copy file1.txt+file2.txt+fil3.txt out.txt` concatenates the files and puts the output in out.txt. There is no similar feature in `Copy-Item`. PowerShell's Copy-Item cmdlet is more similar to xcopy that copy.

Comment: PowerShell is recklessly using its 'power' here. It calls `CopyFileExW` for every match, overwriting the single destination file without asking or informing the user.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to use it for. But It's a fact that PowerShell is more "powerful" than CMD.

Answer (score 1):

1. Powershell is better than CMD, its supposed to be it's the CMD's future.
2. You can't use wildcard in CMD, but if you found a way to do that using powershell, you're good! my advice:

get-childItem -path */path/* -recursive -inculde "*abc.txt*" -Exclude "*/whatever you dont need*" | foreach{ 
      copy-item -path /*path*/ -destination "*/destination/*";
}

good luck!

Comment: Okay thnx @Lior Ben Ahraon